# Python Driver Error: Lights & Vertex Normals

Tags: python, drivers, vertex-groups

Very knew with drivers and python, here. I have a few points to cover to get the full breath of the question to come forward:

1. Can someone please explain why this didn't work as a driver in 3.6 and show me if the more proper expression works for them? I can't seem to get it to work after numerous adjustments.

   ```
    rightarmref.Test = max(min(any((Sun.rotation.quaternion- (rightarmref.matrix_world * vertex)).dot(normal) > 0 for vertex, normal in zip(rightarmref.data.vertices, rightarmref.data.normals))) * (1 if 0.2 <= dot_product <= 0.3 else 0.5), 0.4, 0.1)
   ```

   It reports as syntax error or expression error when making changes here and there. But instead of the mesh 'rightarmref'

***I need it to read a specified vertex group's vertex normals.***

2. To have a clear understanding on the 'why's, the goal is this:

> The more vertex normals within a chosen vertex group is lit by a
> specific light's exact angle and location (more lit means closer the
> vertex normal is angling to the light's center-most), the closer it
> reaches to 0.4 in the value (in this case the color ramp's POS). The
> less lit each vertex normal within a chosen vertex group, the closer
> it reaches to 0.2. Dot product helps determine this measurment of more
> or less by knowing the vertex group's entire vertex normal count.
> However, the speed in which the pace up and down the value is based on
> the piecewise function of slow at 0.2 and below and fast 0.3 and above
> (1.0 in terms of speed), and in-between the POS moves very fast (0.5
> in speed, half of one means it's running faster). The lowest value is
> 0.1 and the highest is 0.4. Similar to a 'easein-skip-easeout' effect in animation. Because the driver expression needs a single line of
> code, this is all what I can figure out.

3. Is there a flaw in this setup's goal? When I add variables (sun and rightarmref; don't know how to add a vertex group) to give it exact detection for the sake of PC optimization if the driver is used very numerously, nothing changed. I'm wondering if the driver has the overall knowledge of what I'm looking for? Imagine the light's detection like that of a cone spinning around, will this setup detect in real-time and change the values up (0.4) and down (0.1), upon being lit by a sun lamp?
4. I know quaternion is ideal if we utilize rotation/angles to avoid gimbal locking and be seamlessly pinpoint no matter how many rotations were performed. But don't know if this is the proper format in the driver. This may not detect a pinpoint location and direction of the sun where to move around but will pinpoint it's exact angle, which is all that matters for stylized/toon purposes.
5. May sound newbish but: Is there really much of a limitation difference between python in blender and python in blender's driver expressions? Haven't also been able to find any difference between syntax from blender 3.6, 4.0, etc in the API. This maybe behind the aspect on why it doesn't work?

My apologies for zeroing too into the question, but maybe this can add more detailed clarity into what to goal is.

Really hope there's a solution to this!
Thank you!

Comment: You can type arbitrary expressions in the driver field but IMO it is by desing restricted to display only a few characters so you don't overengineer things, among other things because drivers are notoriously extremely bad performance wise. It alos points you in the direction of making your own addon, which would be more suited for your goal I think even if the level entry barrier is a bit steeper. You can also use more sophisticated expressions in drivers. Look for "driver namespace" as a keyword

Comment: Sadly I'm to newbie with code to make an addon. That would be cool to do though.